# Dynamic link with absolute URI gets changed to localhost

Tags: php, hyperlink, localhost, href

```php
$refPointer = $site_to_be_extracted . $a->href;
echo $refPointer . '<br>';
```

generates in output (Chrome browser):

```
http://www.hackingwithphp.com/1/1/0/is-this-book-for-you
```

You would expect the following line to generate a correct `<a>` tag. That is a correct link

```php
print '<a href=' . $refPointer . '>' . $a . '</a>';
```

Instead it generates in output:

```
localhost/1/1/0/is-this-book-for-you
```

So both the **protocol** (HTTP) and the **$site_to_be_extracted** (www.hackingwithphp.com) are lost. And replaced by "localhost"
Why? What could be the problem

This is the function where it's all happening. Now it works fine

```php
        include('simple_html_dom.php');
        .
        .
        function createChapterContent ($site_to_be_extracted,     $chapter_to_be_extracted) {
        $html = file_get_html($chapter_to_be_extracted);
        $refPointer;
            foreach($html->find('ol') as $ol) {                                 
            foreach($ol->find('li') as $li) {
                // echo '<br>' . $li->innertext ;
                foreach($li->find('a') as $a) {
    // Original. Causing the reported problem
    // $refPointer = $site_to_be_extracted . $a->href;
    //    echo $refPointer . '<br>';
    // changed to (see below). Now the output is correct
    // Why?
                    $a->href = $site_to_be_extracted . $a->href;
                    $refPointer = $a->href;
                    print '<a href=' . $refPointer . '>' . $li->innertext . '</a>' . '<br>';
                    break;
                }; 
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is $a? Where does $site_to_be_extacted get assigned something? What exactly is the second output it generates, how do you generate it? Not in chrome, as it seems - but from where else?

Comment: This is the function where it's all happening. Now it works fine

Comment: What does `$refPointer;` do at the top of the function?